# How can I modify web content on a mobile browser?

Tags: mobile, web, browser

I want to build a small extension for major browsers that modifies the HTML and CSS of certain pages. On a desktop browser, this can be accomplished easily. On mobile browsers, however, content-modifying extensions are mostly not allowed. (In fact, extensions of any kind are mostly not allowed.) How might I achieve this goal with low friction for the user?

Ideas that wouldn’t work: - a custom keyboard (there are no input tags that should trigger the content modification) - an app or a new browser that does what I want (too much friction for a user to adopt)

Grammarly makes a custom keyboard, which is perfect for them. Honey doesn’t have a mobile extension, but they are building a custom app, from what I’m reading. Neither of these would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "you cant". As you have discovered mobile is much more locked down than desktop.

The fact that popular ad blockers have been forced to write their own browers rather than plugins shows you the limits of modification.

However, you can write an app with an imbedded browser control and modify the content.

Or go further and write your own browser using an open source base browser.